# PHP: using DOMDocument whenever I try to write UTF-8 it writes the hexadecimal notation of it

Tags: php, utf-8, domdocument, hebrew

When I try to write UTF-8 Strings into an XML file using DOMDocument it actually writes the hexadecimal notation of the string instead of the string itself.

for example:

```
&#x5D9;&#x5E8;&#x5D5;&#x5E9;&#x5DC;&#x5D9;&#x5DD;
```

instead of:

```
ירושלים
```

Any ideas how to resolve the issue?

Comment: *(related)* http://de.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php#98209

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, here you go:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('root'));
$dom->documentElement->appendChild(new DOMText('ירושלים'));
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

will work fine, because in this case, the document you constructed will retain the encoding specified as the second argument:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>ירושלים</root>
```

However, once you load XML into a Document that does not specify an encoding, you will lose anything you declared in the constructor, which means:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadXml('<root/>'); // missing prolog
$dom->documentElement->appendChild(new DOMText('ירושלים'));
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

will not have an encoding of utf-8:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>&#x5D9;&#x5E8;&#x5D5;&#x5E9;&#x5DC;&#x5D9;&#x5DD;</root>
```

So if you loadXML something, make sure it is

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root/>');
$dom->documentElement->appendChild(new DOMText('ירושלים'));
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

and it will work as expected.

As an alternative, you can also [specify the encoding](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.encoding) after loading the document.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to output UTF-8 with DOMDocument, you need to specify that. Simple, isn't it? If you already smell a trick question, you're not too far off, but on first sight, it really is straight forward.

Consider the following (UTF-8 encoded) code-example that outputs hexadecimal entities:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<root>ירושלים</root>');
$dom->save('php://output');
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>&#x5D9;&#x5E8;&#x5D5;&#x5E9;&#x5DC;&#x5D9;&#x5DD;</root>
```

As written, if you want to output this as UTF-8, you need to specify it, and it is straight forward:

```
...
$dom->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$dom->save('php://output');
```

The output then is in UTF-8 *explicitly*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>ירושלים</root>
```

So much for the straight forward part. If you are interested in the dirty little details, you are free to read on - if not, please do not ask *"why?"* :).

I just wrote *"in UTF-8 **explicitly**"* because also in the first example the output is UTF-8 encoded, the XML just contained hexadecimal entities which is perfectly valid - even in UTF-8!

You already notice that I start with nit-picking here, but remember: [UTF-8 *is* the *default encoding* of XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding).

And if you now start to say: Hey wait, if the default encoding is UTF-8 anyway, why does PHPs *DOMDocument* use the entities in the first place?

Well the truth is, it does *not* contrary to the finding in the question. Not *always*.

See the following example which is using an XML-comment instead of a node value containing the Ivrit letters:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml('<root><!-- ירושלים --></root>');
$dom->save('php://output');
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><!-- ירושלים --></root>
```

Okay, all clear? So the dirty little secret here is: Whether you've got those XML entities in there or not - for the document it does not make a difference, it is just a different form of writing the same XML character data. And you already feel invited: Lets try [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect) instead for the first example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML("<root><![CDATA[ירושלים]]></root>");
$dom->save('php://output');
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><![CDATA[ירושלים]]></root>
```

As this demonstrates like with the XML-comment example before, there are no XML entities used here. Well, they would not be valid anyway, like with the XML-comment example.

For the overview lets create an example that contains all these:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML("<!-- ירושלים --><root>&#x5D9;רושלים <![CDATA[ירושלים]]></root>");
$dom->save('php://output');
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- ירושלים -->
<root>&#x5D9;&#x5E8;&#x5D5;&#x5E9;&#x5DC;&#x5D9;&#x5DD; <![CDATA[ירושלים]]></root>
```

Lessons learned:

- UTF-8 is always used. Just some entities are used in PCDATA unless the UTF-8 encoding is specified. [If a different to UTF-8 encoding is specified, different rules apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16328079/367456).
- You can not specify if you want to use entities or not for output by *loading* an XML document as UTF-8 encoded string in PHPs *DOMDocument* per-se. Not even with [libxml flags](http://php.net/libxml.constants) nor by providing a BOM. <sup>[1]</sup>
- You can specify that you do not want to use entities by setting the documents encoding to UTF-8.
- If you can, you can manipulate the input string having an XML-Declaration specifying the documents encoding [as outlined in gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3575326/367456).

> ***Tip:*** If your string has an XML-Declaration that mismatches the strings encoding or you want to change either of both *before* loading the string into *DOMDocument* you need to change the XML-Declaration and/or re-encode the string. This has been covered [in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15495409/367456) to the question [PHP XMLReader, get the version and encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15477999/367456) by showing how the [`XMLRecoder` class](https://gist.github.com/hakre/5194634) works.

And that's it hopefully.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Probably if you load from a HTTP request and you provide stream context and flag the character encoding via meta-data - but this should be tested first, I do not know. That the BOM does not work is somewhat a sign that all these things do not work.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently passing the documentElement as $node to saveXML works around this, although I can't say I understand why.

e.g.

```
$dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
```

rather than:

```
$dom->saveXML();
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php#88525

Comment: The likely difference is the `$dom` object wasn't initialized with a character set for the document in the constructor, but the document element does have some sense of encoding in it's context.

Answer (score 1):

To the point answer is:

When your function starts, right after you get the content, do this:

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

And then start the new document etc. Check this as example:

```
if ( empty( $content ) ) {
    return false;
}
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->LoadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Then do whatever you were intending to do with your code.

Answer (score 0):

When I created the DOMDocument for writing, i added the following parameters:

```
dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
```

these parameters caused the UTF-8 string to be written as is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);

// dirty fix
foreach ($doc->childNodes as $item)
  if ($item->nodeType == XML_PI_NODE)
    $doc->removeChild($item); // remove hack
$doc->encoding = 'UTF-8'; // insert proper
```