# DomDocument and special characters

Tags: php, utf-8, domdocument

This is my code:

```
$oDom = new DOMDocument();
$oDom->loadHTML("èàéìòù");
echo $oDom->saveHTML();
```

This is the output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>&Atilde;&uml;&Atilde;&nbsp;&Atilde;&copy;&Atilde;&not;&Atilde;&sup2;&Atilde;&sup1;</p></body></html>
```

I want this output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>èàéìòù</p></body></html>
```

I've tried with ...

```
$oDom = new DomDocument('4.0', 'UTF-8');
```

or with 1.0 and other stuffs but nothing.

Another thing ...
There is a way to obtain the same untouched HTML?
For example with this html in input `<p>hello!</p>` obtain the same output `<p>hello!</p>` using DOMDocument only for parsing the DOM and to do some substitutions inside the tags.

Comment: given you've got `&Atilde;`, in the output, something's mangling your UTF-8 and making it look like iso-8859 or similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP DOMDocument loadHTML not encoding UTF-8 correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Solution:

```
$oDom = new DOMDocument();
$oDom->encoding = 'utf-8';
$oDom->loadHTML( utf8_decode( $sString ) ); // important!

$sHtml = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">';
$sHtml .= $oDom->saveHTML( $oDom->documentElement ); // important!
```

The `saveHTML()` method works differently specifying a node.
You can use the main node (`$oDom->documentElement`) adding the desired `!DOCTYPE` manually.
Another important thing is `utf8_decode()`.
All the attributes and the other methods of the `DOMDocument` class, in my case, don't produce the desired result.

Comment: To make this work with other characters outside of the ISO-8859-1 set, you need to use multi-byte decoding. So that characters like chinese or the euro sign with also be properly encoded.

`$oDom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($sString, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));`

[see here for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218230/php-domdocument-loadhtml-not-encoding-utf-8-correctly)

Comment: I almost lose my mind trying to solve this! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Try to set the encoding type **after** you have loaded the HTML.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->encoding = 'utf-8';
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[Other way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625173/php-xml-dom-translates-special-chars-to-xyy)

Answer (score 7):

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$str = htmlentities($str);
$dom->loadHTML(utf8_decode($str));
$dom->encoding = 'utf-8';
.
.
.
$str = $dom->saveHTML();
$str = html_entity_decode($str);
```

The above code worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why the marked answer didn't work for my problem. But this one did.

ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

```
<?php

            // checks if the content we're receiving isn't empty, to avoid the warning
            if ( empty( $content ) ) {
                return false;
            }

            // converts all special characters to utf-8
            $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');

            // creating new document
            $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

            //turning off some errors
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

            // it loads the content without adding enclosing html/body tags and also the doctype declaration
            $doc->LoadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

            // do whatever you want to do with this code now

?>
```

Answer (score 5):

The issue appears to be known, according to the user comments on the [manual page at php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).  Solutions suggested there include putting

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

in the document before you put any strings with non-ASCII chars in.

Another hack suggests putting

```
<?xml encoding="UTF-8">
```

as the first text in the document and then removing it at the end.

Nasty stuff. Smells like a bug to me.

Answer (score 4):

This way:

```
/**
 * @param string $text
 * @return DOMDocument
 */
private function buildDocument($text)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->loadHTML('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">' . $text);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

    return $dom;
}
```

Comment: I needed it for an API endpoint that a mobile app uses. And only this solution worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was:

```
$doc->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

credit: https://davidwalsh.name/domdocument-utf8-problem

Comment: that fixed my issue, on turkish chars.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me but this one did the job:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents('my_file.html');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($fileContent, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$dom->encoding = 'utf-8';
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
$html = html_entity_decode($html, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to set [substituteEntities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.substituteentities) when you create the DOMDocument object.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);

// dirty fix
foreach ($doc->childNodes as $item) {
    if ($item->nodeType == XML_PI_NODE) {
        $doc->removeChild($item); // remove hack
    }
}

?>
```

Credits: https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251