# How can I show only <h1> tags in The Loop?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, if-statement

Is there a way to force The Loop to show only `<h1>` tags from the content of a post, while ignoring all other tags (`h2`, `p`, `hr`... )?

```
  <div id="intro">
  <?php
  $hm_intro = new WP_query(array(
  'p' => 375,
  'post_type' => 'any',
  'posts_per_page' => 1
  ));
  if($hm_intro->have_posts()) : while($hm_intro->have_posts()) : $hm_intro->the_post();

  //Here I want display only the <h1></h1> from the_content().

  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  endif;
  ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting all values from h1 tags using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299033/getting-all-values-from-h1-tags-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse all the H1s out of the post content with [domDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
if($hm_intro->have_posts()) : while($hm_intro->have_posts()) : $hm_intro->the_post();

    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML(get_the_content());

    $headings = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1');

    foreach ($heading as $h){
        echo '<h1>' . $h->textContent . '</h1>';
    }

endwhile;
```

Comment: Perfect ! Simple and functional.

There's only one problem, but my issue was resolved .

The problem is that apparently the DomDocument does not recognize UTF -8. Do you know any solution to force content to accept special characters like `à`, `Ô` or `ç`? Anyway, thank you for helping me!

Comment: @rdllngr i havent actually had to deal with that myself, but this SO answer looks like it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573258/domdocument-and-special-characters

Comment: Do not worry . I found a solution right now. I will post the final code in my question . Thank you again. That made my day. :D

Comment: No problem. If you have found a solution you should post it as an answer, rather than in your question

Comment: @rdllngr You should post it as an answer ONLY if it is a significantly different solution that was provided in an existing answer. Otherwise a comment saying "I also added a line or two that flibbered the gibbet" would be appropriate.

Comment: I agree. I'm sorry. The encoding solution is similar to the question that Steven showed me. Thanks again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573258/domdocument-and-special-characters