# Special chars with images

Tags: summernote, chars

I'm using the josh admin template which has a blog. The blog works with summernote. When i'm using special chars in German (like ü,ä,...) the blog shows it as special chars and not as "Umlaut". I'm also using the picture upload support which stores the pic in the db.

I searched lot of time but no success. What i have to do, that summernote knows the special chars in german?

Here an example from the db:

```
Bereits um 7 Uhr morgens versammel-
ten sich die Mitglieder des VGWM bei
der Post in Matzingen. Mit einem ger&Atilde;&curren;umigen Car startete dann die Reise
auf der Autobahn in Richtung Westen.
Trotzdem an diesem fr&Atilde;&frac14;hen Samstag-
morgen viele Strassenbenutzer unter-
wegs waren, kamen wir nach z&Atilde;&frac14;giger
Fahrt an unserer ersten Destination
ein. Kaffeehalt.</span></p><p><span style="font-size: 12.000000pt; font-family: 'Arial,Bold'"><br></span></p><p><img data-filename="Screenshot at Nov. 06 13-02-25.png" style="width: 703px;" src="http://test.app:8000/uploads/blog/5a004fd6ed95e.png"><span style="font-size: 12.000000pt; font-family: 'Arial,Bold'">&Atilde;&#130;&nbsp;</span></p><p><span style="font-size: 12.000000pt; font-family: 'Arial,Bold'"><br></span></p><p>
```

Comment: Check your encoding, either on the server or the database. Normally, you should use something like UTF-8.

Comment: After searchiing with your hint, i found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573258/domdocument-and-special-characters#_=

Comment: If this solves your question, you can add an answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: Solution was found here:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573258/domdocument-and-special-characters#_=)