# Escape newline encryption (&#13) in XML while update using DOM PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

I tried to update xml node value by posted PHP value. My problem, after save the XML, 
can look like

```
<name>test&#13;
test123</name>
```

My expect result is

```
<name>test
test123</name>
```

My source

```
$xml_Document = new DOMDocument();
$xml_Document->load('test.xml');

$employees = $xml_Document->getElementsByTagName("employees");

foreach( $employees as $employee )
{
$names = $employee->getElementsByTagName("name");

$names->item(0)->nodeValue = $_POST["text1"];

}

$xml_Document->save('test.xml');
```

Comment: see if this one solves it: [php: using DomDocument whenever I try to write UTF-8 it writes the hexadecimal notation of it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575109/php-using-domdocument-whenever-i-try-to-write-utf-8-it-writes-the-hexadecimal-no)

Comment: libxml2 seems to explicitly escapes `\r` to `&#13;`

Answer (score 2):

I think this will fix your problem $names->item(0)->nodeValue = str_replace(chr(13), '', $_POST["text1"]);

Comment: BTW it would be helpful to know when \r becomes &#13; before saving? Or just after saving?