# How do I make the ö character appear properly in an XML file created via PHP?

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, formatting, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php: using DomDocument whenever I try to write UTF-8 it writes the hexadecimal notation of it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575109/php-using-domdocument-whenever-i-try-to-write-utf-8-it-writes-the-hexadecimal-no)

Here is a snippet of code:

```
echo "<char>".$row{'char'}."</char>";
```

row{'char'} is pulling back the german character ö from the database. In PHP, how can I convert that to the correct encoding to be used properly in XML?

Is there a PHP function that can convert everything as needed to the correct format for XML? Or do I need to do it character by character, like so?

```
echo "<format>".str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row{'format'})."</format>";
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the XML processing instruction contain the encoding, e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: What is the encoding in your database? iso-8859-1? utf-8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing what encoding you have in your database and what encoding you want in your XML output it's hard to be specific, but the [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function could be useful to do the conversion.

Also. you should really consider using an XML DOM instead of outputting xml-as-plaintext with `echo`. Check out for example [Reading and writing the XML DOM with PHP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-xmldomphp/)
. If you don't, you will most likely end up with other strange problems with your xml output down the road.

Trust me, I've been there. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Passing the data pulled from the database through htmlentities() should do that. It changes "ö" to `"&ouml;"`.

```
echo "<char>".htmlentities($row{'char'})."</char>";
```

[The PHP Manual](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: An XML document isn't necessarily a HTML document; Encoding 'ö' as &ouml; might not be valid or produce what's expected.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I realised after re-reading the question.