# How can I grab the entire content inside `<body>` tag with regex?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

How can I grab the entire content inside `<body>` tag with regex?

For instance,

```
<html><body><p><a href="#">xx</a></p>

<p><a href="#">xx</a></p></body></html>
```

I want to return this only,

```
<p><a href="#">xx</a></p>

<p><a href="#">xx</a></p>
```

Or any other better ideas? maybe DOM but I have to use `saveHTML();` then it will return `doctype` and `body` tag...

[HTML Purifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891416/an-alternative-to-php-tidy) is a pain to use so I decide not to use it. I thought regex could be the next best option for my disaster.

Comment: A regex like this one doesn't work for you `<body>(.*)</body>`?

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php/3577662#3577662

Comment: @sahid - no, what about, `<body class="large-text"> ... </body>`

Comment: Don't use regexes.  http://htmlparsing.com/php.html gives you examples of how to use a proper HTML parser.  In fact, if you're using simple_html_dom, it's as simple as `file_get_html('http://www.google.com/')->plaintext;`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
preg_match("/<body[^>]*>(.*?)<\/body>/is", $html, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will be the contents of the body tag

Comment: See the valid(!) HTML examples at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege/702222#702222 and see how you fail with a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("~<body.*?>(.*?)<\/body>~is", $html, $match);
print_r($match);
```