# Is it possible to run tidy at google app engine PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, tidy

It seems like google app engine php doesn't have tidy extension, my question is , is there any way to use tidy on google app engine php?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The tidy extension is bundled with PHP 5 and greater, and is installed using the --with-tidy configure option. So if phpinfo() does not mention tidy I guess there's no (easy) way to be able to use it.

App Engine includes the PHP 5.4 standard library. You can include other pure PHP libraries with your application by putting the code in your application directory. If you make a symbolic link to a module's directory in your application directory, appcfg.py will follow the link and include the module in your app. Maybe this approach would work with the (old) [PECL tidy package](http://pecl.php.net/package/tidy), although I'm not really sure about that.

Comment: Thanks Nick, so I guess it's not easy to do it.

Comment: I checked phpinfo on a test instance yesterday and can confirm that the current App Engine PHP version 5.4.19 does not seem to include tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use `tidy` package at all in Google App Engine. You can see all enabled extensions from  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#enabled_extensions

Few extensions you can enable though but `tidy` is not one of them. I would recommend to find some alternatives of tidy. You can also take a look at [An alternative to php tidy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891416/an-alternative-to-php-tidy)