# <script> embed gets removed with HTML Purifier (latest 4.8.0)

Tags: attributes, tags, embed, htmlpurifier

Twitter embed code example:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Some text here <a href="https://some.twitter.link">pic.twitter.com/...</a></p>&mdash; Some user <a href="http://other.twitter.link">August 10, 2016</a></blockquote>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

After purifying it, I get only the `blockquote` part and `script` is removed. Searched a lot and tried some different things.

---

`$hp_config->set('HTML.SafeScripting', ['//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js']);`
Isn't helpful, because Twitter embed is just an example and Facebook embed even gives not src, but full `function()` and I'm using lots of different embed sources.

---

`$hp_config->set('HTML.Trusted', true);` leaves `script` tag, but removes `async` and `charset` attributes.

---

```
$def = $hp_config->getHTMLDefinition();
$def->addAttribute('script', 'async', 'Text#');
$def->addAttribute('script', 'charset', 'Charsets#utf-8');
```

This doesn't help either. I don't know if I'm doing it right. Couldn't find detailed example.

---

---

I also use Purifier to clean `iframe` embeds, but for these I use:

```
$hp_config->set('HTML.SafeIframe', true);
$hp_config->set('URI.SafeIframeRegexp', '%%');
```

Only some trusted users can edit these embeds, so I allow all sources.

So how can I get `script` tags left as is, but fix everything else (like closing tags and other tags' attributes)?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about what are you trying to achieve with HTML Purifier? Usually the removal of `<script>` tags and JavaScript in general is the precise purpose. (If you are using it to sanitise things, can you tell me what kind of scripts you want to allow? i.e. How are safe scripts defined in your use-case?)

Comment: Regarding the attributes, `async` is likely being removed because HTML Purifier doesn't know that attribute. A lot of HTML Purifier's protection stems from that it does HTML-aware whitelisting of tags _and_ attributes. That means it has to know and understand all HTML you want to use. `async` is an HTML5 attribute, and HTML Purifier does not (I think) support HTML5 yet. You'd have to change it. See http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html

Comment: I just want to leave `script` and `iframe` embeds as someone pastes them from websites like Youtube, Twitter, Instagram, Pinterest, Facebook, some local media websites and so on. Iv'e got sorted everything with `iframe`s, but `script` tags either gets whole removed or just attributes. How can I get `script` tags left as is, but fix everything else (like closing tags and other tags' attributes)? Updated the question to make it more clear what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, I've seen requests for HTML5 coming since 2011, but still no response about it. That's why I tried to add these attributes to `script` tag to definition, but I have no idea if I'm doing it right. As I said, couldn't find any proper example for it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use-case - do you trust your users not to supply malicious HTML? In that case, are you trying to use HTML Purifier to tidy your HTML rather than sanitise it? HTML Purifier is intended as a security module. If you just want to tidy your HTML, maybe try https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5 ?

Comment: Re: `async`, have you tried `$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true); $def->addAttribute('script', 'async', 'Enum#async');` (in place of the example at "Add an attribute" of the customize documentation with `target` for `a`-tags)?

Comment: Maybe Tidy HTML5 would be a solution, but couldn't figure out how to use it in PHP if possible. And `$def->addAttribute('script', 'async', 'Enum#async');` also should clear the `async` attribute, because it's just empty attribute and not `async="async"`. But I'll try it later.

Comment: Actually, `<script async>` should be equivalent to `<script async="async">` (it's a boolean attribute -- see https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2). That said, I'm not sure if that's still true for HTML5 - and I'm also not sure if HTML Purifier would know to assume that equivalence. It's something to play around with.

Comment: Re: Tidy, this might help: http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Comment: Will look into it later and let You know. Thanks

Comment: HTML Purifier supports the `Bool` attribute type directly, by the way, I managed to miss that in my reading earlier. Armed with that knowledge I've tossed you an answer. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123859/discussion-between-pinkgothic-and-cronus).

Answer (score 0):

Judging from our comment conversation, you appear to be more interested in tidying your HTML rather than sanitising it. As such, HTML Purifier is probably not the right tool for you. You could look into [PHP's Tidy module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) (a wrapper for HTML Tidy), or check out [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6891416/245790).

If you do want to teach HTML Purifier to accept script tags, `HTML.Trusted` is the right setting. That said, HTML Purifier does not currently support HTML5 and therefore does not understand HTML5-only attributes like `async`. To teach HTML Purifier that attribute, you need to follow the instructions on [the Enduser "Customize" documentation](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html).

In your case the first step to take is to add this to your code:

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'enduser-customize.html tutorial');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null); // remove this later!
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addAttribute('script', 'async', 'Bool#async');
```

This teaches HTML Purifier that `async` is an expected boolean value for the tag. If you want to allow the `charset` attribute, try:

```
$def->addAttribute('script', 'charset', 'Enum#utf-8');
```

...or whatever other charsets you want to support. If you want to support any value:

```
$def->addAttribute('script', 'charset', 'CDATA');
```