# DOMDocument with XPath Encoding problems. [?] A lot of tests

Tags: php, dom, xpath, encoding

```
$msg = "<body><a>áéíóú☻♥♦♣</a></body>";
$temp_dom = new DOMDocument();    
$temp_dom->loadHTML($msg);    
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($temp_dom);   
$ele = $dom_xpath->query('//a')->item(0);

echo "<pre>";
echo "Original: $msg\n";
echo $ele->nodeValue;     
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Original: áéíóú☻♥♦♣
Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãºâ»â¥â¦â£
```

The current document encoding is utf-8.
I tried ANSI too and same problem happened.

utf8_decode solves the problem

```
echo utf8_decode($ele->nodeValue);
```

But the thing is, I use a lot of attributes and a lot of functions that I would have to use utf8_decode in each one of them, and I believe that's not the correct thing to do.
Someone know how could I do this?

Please use this test and test it before posting a result, because I've already tried a lot of things.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php: using DomDocument whenever I try to write UTF-8 it writes the hexadecimal notation of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575109/php-using-domdocument-whenever-i-try-to-write-utf-8-it-writes-the-hexadecimal-n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you need to tell DOMDocument what the encoding is as the HTML is parsed.  You can't do this by setting the `encoding` option. (I believe that affects how the document is output with `saveHTML`.)

The slightly hackish way to do this is to insert a statement of the encoding into the document.  You can do this simply by inserting `'<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'` before the HTML you are parsing.

```
<?php

$msg = "<body><a>áéíóú☻♥♦♣</a></body>";
$temp_dom = new DOMDocument();    


$temp_dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $msg);    
$temp_dom->encoding = 'UTF-8';
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($temp_dom);   
$ele = $dom_xpath->query('//a')->item(0);

echo "<pre>";
echo "Original: $msg\n";
echo $ele->nodeValue;     
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```plain
<pre>Original: <body><a>áéíóú☻♥♦♣</a></body>
áéíóú☻♥♦♣</pre>
```

Note, however, that this does insert an extra node as a child of the document object (a `DOMProcessingInstruction` to be precise), so be aware of this if you are doing anything with `$temp_dom->childNodes` or suchlike.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I requested. ;D Actually the trick is declaring the DOCTYPE (<?xml encoding="UTF-8">), I didn't realize that the XPath could consider this to define the encoding to use. Thanks. :)